# Contiki Timer Synchronization

Tags: contiki

I have started recently programming in Contiki. Currently I want to synchronize the timer of a set of nodes. To achieve this, I am using the functions of the header file `timesynch.h`. I include it as a normal h file at the top of my code. But whenever I try to use the functions inside it (`timesynch_init()` for instance) I get the following error message:

> xmas_sync.co: In function `process_thread_example_collect_process':
>   /home/user/contiki-2.7/examples/rime/xmas_sync.c:108: undefined reference to`timesynch_init'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [xmas_sync.native] Error 1

I do not know if I need to do something else to use these synchronization functions. My code is based on the collect example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable timesync in application's or platform's configuration. On most platforms, it is not done by default.

To enable it in application's configuration, there are two options:

1. Modify `Makefile` to include this define in CFLAGS:

   CFLAGS += -DTIMESYNCH_CONF_ENABLED=1
2. Create a `project-conf.h` file, change `Makefile` to enable including this file:

   `CFLAGS += -DPROJECT_CONF_H=\"project-conf.h\"`

   and enable the timesync in `project-conf.h` by adding this line

   `#define TIMESYNCH_CONF_ENABLED 1`

Also, it looks like you're to build the example for the `native` (x86) platform. To build for a sensor node hardware platform, set the `TARGET` variable, e.g. run `make TARGET=sky example-collect`.

Comment: Hi. I tried the two options you mentioned but it did not work. Then I changed the platform to z1 and it compiled. It is weird because the Contiki Documentation says that Sky supports time synchronization.